# Connecting morphism in an abelian category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, exact-sequence

I'm trying to understand how one gets the long exact sequence in homology  from a short exact sequence of chain complexes in an arbitrary abelian category.

So far I have the commutative diagram below, with all rows exact:
[image]

We examine the homologies
[image]

Where $\bar H$ is the dual object of the homology, which is isomorphic to it.

Now the author of the book I'm following (Osborne's *Basic Homological Algebra*, p.231) says that the *connecting morphism* is defined as the homology map induced by $f_2$: $$(f_2)_\ast =\delta:\bar H\rightarrow H$$
I do not follow. How do we know such an arrow exists? In what precise sense is it induced by $f_2$?

***Added:*** I would like a detailed explanation; "Just apply the universal properties" is not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you heard of the Snake Lemma?

Comment: @Hayden yep. Unless I'm mistaken, I'm asking about the connecting morphism given by the snake lemma. My question comes from the process of proving it in the book I'm following, so I don't want to use it.

Comment: Ah, I see, just thought I'd mention it since you never explicitly said "snake lemma" (though your diagram is exactly what it applies to).

Comment: I don't know a way to make $(f_2)_*$ the image of $f_2$ under an operation $(-)_*$, but an explicit (and element-free) definition of the connecting homomorphism is given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/74872/45082).

Comment: @tcamps I don't understand "This then induces a map on quotients $B^{\prime \prime}/A \rightarrow A^\prime /\operatorname{Im}a$ which is precisely the desired map $\operatorname{Ker}c\rightarrow \operatorname{Coker}a.$" Explicitly, how is this map induced? I wasn't able to figure it out by myself. Also, it is $A^\prime /\operatorname{Im}a$ and not $A^\prime /\operatorname{Im}A$, right?

Comment: You can construct the connecting morphism by using the [mapping cone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cone_%28homological_algebra%29). For instance, see Lemma 9.1.20 in [my notes](http://zll22.user.srcf.net/writing/homotopical-algebra/2015-01-15-Main.pdf).

Comment: Exterior, you're absolutely right, that really isn't clear. @ZhenLin that will sometimes give the connecting homormophism in homology, but don't the 2-term chain complexes $A \to A'$ and $B \to B'$ have to cofibrant for $C \to C'$ to be quasiisomorphic to the mapping cone? Nice notes btw.

Comment: There is no need to bring in any model structure. For some reason homological algebra is very nice.

Comment: @tcamps could you by any chance explain what's going on in detail?

Comment: @ZhenLin your notes look great, but I'd rather (at least for the first time) understand the "primitive proof".

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/74871/200415) question and answer?

Comment: @tracing yes, that is the same answer tcamps mentioned in a previous comment, which I asked about above.

Comment: @Exterior: Sorry, I'd missed that.  But I see you also had a question about the map $B''/A \to A'/\text{Im } A$.   This is something general: we have a map $B'' \to A',$ and a sub object $A$ of $B''$.  There is then an induced morphism from the quotient of $B''$ by $A$ to the quotient of $A'$ by the image of $A$ in $A'$.

Comment: @tracing I believe you, I just haven't been able to prove its existence. I would much appreciate a detailed walkthrough :)